# What is actually passed as a parameter to the function?

Tags: python

```
 def f(a):
     for i in a:
         print i 
 >>> f(i for i in [1,2,3])
 1
 2
 3
 >>> f([i for i in [1,2,3]])
 1
 2
 3
 >>> f((i for i in (1,)))
 1
```

Did I pass a tupple or list in the first example?

What are the differeces between them?

Comment: You passed a generator. Try adding the line `print type(a)` to your function.

Comment: Each element in the list iteratively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass a generator and a list:

```
>>> def f(a):
...     print type(a)
...     for i in a:
...         print i 
... 
>>> f(i for i in [1,2,3])
<type 'generator'>
1
2
3
>>> 
>>> f([i for i in [1,2,3]])
<type 'list'>
1
2
3
>>> f((i for i in (1,)))
<type 'generator'>
1
>>>
```

Both are iterable in a for-loop, however it works differently. Generator executes a statement every iteration and list (or another Iterables) are a piece of data, all of its elements are present without any operation. 
More about generators [here](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html#generators)

Answer (score 0):

You don't really want to check types because you would defeat the purpose of polymorphism. However, if you really want to know the type of the object, you can call the built-in type() function.

```
#Python 3.x
a=[1,2,3]
b=(1,2,3)
type(a)
<class 'list'>
type(b)
<class 'tuple'>
```